# Adding footprints to multiple components at once in Altium

Tags: altium

I have a library with a few hundreds of passives, each with 2 footprints (ie. 0603_IPC_A, 0603_IPC_B).
I want to replace these footprints with new ones from a different library. Is there a way to do it for multiple components at once so I don't have to traverse them 1 by 1?
I tried through SchLib List panel, but there is no column "footprints", only "current footprint" which when changed to a new value "A" just adds "A" to the available footprints.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this using the "Model Manager".  How it works depends on the version of Altium you have.  It's a little confusing, but way better than doing them one by one!   In Altium 17, when you have a schematic library open, click on "Tools" and then "Model Manager".   The newer (18+) versions with the different UI are probably similar, but we run 17 here.